# Find the area of the adjoining figure

Tags: geometry

In the adjoining figure, $ABCD$ is a trapezium in which $AB||DC$; $AB=7$ $cm$; $AD=BC=5$ $cm$ and distance between $AB$ and $DC$ is $4$ $cm$. Find the length of $DC$ and hence, find the area of trap.$ABCD$.

What I did try is in the attached picture. Please do find it.[image]

Comment: It looks like the wrong diagram to me. The right diagram would make this easy.

Comment: How about now, #Mark Bennet

Comment: it seems I can't see what you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$DL^2 = AD^2 - AL^2$

=> $DL^2 = 9$

=> $DL = 3$

the same way $MC=3$

$LM = AB = 7$

=> $DC = DL + LM + MC$

=> $DC = 3 + 7+ 3$

=> $DC = 13$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  The distance between $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$ is the perpendicular distance, so $\overline{AL} \perp \overline{CD}$ and $\overline{BM} \perp \overline {CD}$.  Thus, $\triangle ALD$ and $\triangle BCM$ are right triangles.  Use the Pythagorean Theorem to determine the lengths of $\overline{DL}$ and $\overline{CM}$.  Once you know those lengths, you can determine the length of $\overline{CD}$, which would enable you to apply the area formula $$A = \frac{1}{2}(b_1 + b_2)h$$